# peak memory usage of processes launched by multiprocessing.pool in Python

Tags: python-3.x, memory, multiprocessing

I am launching multiple processes using multiprocessing.Pool and I need know the peak memory usage among these processes.

I googled it quite a bit but still no luck to find a straightforward way to solve the problem. Basically I want something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(8)
p.map(function, cmd)
GetPeakMemoryUsageof(p)
```

Or if that is not possible, then each process's peak memory can also work for my problem.

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.memory_info) module allows to iterate over processes and get their memory information.

The Pool itself does not expose any introspection capability.

Comment: Will psutil affect my program's runtime? Since it is profiling my program.

Comment: It does not profile your program. It uses OS native calls to get the required information. It takes the same resources software like top and htop do.